# How to remove previous polyline automatically before adding new path

Tags: angular, leaflet, polyline

I am working on Angular using Leaflet map . My project is getting data json coordinates for flight path . My code below is working fine , but the problem is l have repeat polyline path on map while data is updating  . l did some steps to remove previous polyline path and shows new path , but still l have same issues .

```
export class MapTrackBeforPage implements OnInit {
    map: Map;
    poly:L.Polyline
    fg = L.featureGroup()

    protected points: { lat: number, lng: number }[] = [];

    constructor(
        private http: HTTP,
       public zone : NgZone) {

    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.getmarker()
        this.leafletMap()
    }

    leafletMap() {
        // In setView add latLng and zoom
        this.map = new Map('Map_id', { attributionControl: false }).setView([33, 44], 6);
        this.fg =L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map)

        return tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Baghdad Int`l Airport © 2019',
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }

    async getmarker() {

        this.zone.runTask(()=>{
            setInterval(()=>{
                this.http.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'', {}, {})
                .then(data => {
                    this.fg.clearLayers()
                    let getdata = JSON.parse(data.data)
                    console.log(getdata)
                    this.AddPath(JSON.parse(data.data))
                })
            },5000)
        })

    }

    AddPath(path) {
        // Flight path
        for (let datas of path) {

            this.points.push({ lat: datas.lat, lng: datas.lng })
            console.log(this.points)
            this.poly = new L.Polyline([this.points], { color: 'red', weight: 3 }).addTo(this.fg);
            // zoom the map to the polyline
            this.map.fitBounds(this.fg.getBounds())

        }
        new L.Marker(this.points[0], {
        icon: new L.DivIcon({
        html: ` <img src="assets/icon/B733.png" style="width:25px"/>`,
        iconSize: [20, 20],
        })

        }).addTo(this.map)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your polylines to a featuregroup, then you can clear the group.

```
let fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map)
async getmarker() {

    let poly: L.Polyline
    poly.remove()

    interval(5000).subscribe(()=>{
        this.http.get('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {}, {})
        .then(data => {
            fg.clearLayers(); //<----
            let getdata = JSON.parse(data.data)
            console.log(getdata)

            // Flight path
            for (let datas of JSON.parse(data.data)['trail']) {

                this.points.push({ lat: datas.lat, lng: datas.lng })
                console.log(this.points)
                 poly = new L.Polyline([this.points], { color: 'red', weight: 3 }).addTo(fg); //<---- Change to fg
                // zoom the map to the polyline

                this.map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds()) //<---- Change to fg

            }

    })

}
```

Maybe you have to change the init from the `fg` var, I don't know if this is right for angluar

**Update: Error searching**

Try:

```
map: Map;
    poly:L.Polyline
    fg : L.FeatureGroup() // ":" and "F"
```

or

```
leafletMap() {
        // In setView add latLng and zoom
        this.map = new Map('Map_id', { attributionControl: false }).setView([33, 44], 6);


        var t = tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Baghdad Int`l Airport © 2019',
        }).addTo(this.map);
        this.fg =L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map) //<--------
        return t; //<--------
    }
```

or

```
leafletMap() {
        // In setView add latLng and zoom
        this.map = new Map('Map_id', { attributionControl: false }).setView([33, 44], 6);


        var t = tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Baghdad Int`l Airport © 2019',
        }).addTo(this.map);
        this.fg = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(this.map) //<--------
        return t;
    }
```

what do you get in the console?:

```
 for (let datas of path) {

            this.points.push({ lat: datas.lat, lng: datas.lng })
            console.log(this.points)
            this.poly = new L.Polyline([this.points], { color: 'red', weight: 3 }).addTo(this.fg);
            // zoom the map to the polyline
            this.map.fitBounds(this.fg.getBounds())

        }
console.log(fg); //<----
```

Comment: have you created the featuregroup correct and global?

Comment: Aah I think that you create the featuregroup and add them to the map, before you init the map variable

Comment: you can check out here [https://i.ibb.co/djLjL9w/Capture.png]

Comment: In which line to you get the error? Else try `new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(this.map)`

Comment: l dont have error now after l adjust the code. but the polyline not show on map !

Comment: what happens when you remove `poly.remove()`?

Comment: Nothing , because l already deleted `poly.remove()` . my code working now without error and my data also are reloading . but l still have polyline not showing on map

Comment: l have updated my code in question . take look please

Comment: I updated my code depending on your answer . still l have no polyline shows on map . also in `console.log(fg)` nothing have show !

Comment: what do you get after `this.map = new Map('Map_id', { attributionControl: false }).setView([33, 44], 6);
        this.fg =L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map)` `console.log(this.fg)`?

Comment: ok that is good! Your fg obj is created but you don't get them in the call `getmarker`. Are you sure that this.fg calls the global fg and not the (not existing) fg in the http request? Try `var that = this; this.zone.runTask(()=>{ [...]  .then(data => {
                    that.fg.clearLayers()`

Comment: same issues , nothing shows on map . my previous code was showing path on map , but this code is not

Comment: Can you try to create a fiddle / online demo?

Comment: l cant because he is live tracking on private server

Comment: hello again , l created online demo , you can check how is polyline is duplicated . [ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebtppj ]

Comment: Hi, I don't see a duplicated line, where should they be? If you mean the Line that connects the last and the first Point, I think this is because you are useing "Polygon" instead of "Polyline" in app.componet.ts 4061. Also this is no more a leaflet Problem, because you are useing google maps now

Comment: thank you for replying, Yes that what l mean , i have line that connects the last and the first Point, on map by using polyline  . l want remove those point . Also l am using Leaflet map and this code demo is old  but it is same idea which i  have .

Comment: This is what i have in image . https://i.ibb.co/xg10QMp/81001622-752857165208799-7663220613917442048-n.jpg Line that connects the last and the first Point

Answer (score 0):

To disable the "connection" between the last and the first point, you can remove or not print the last point in the array. I looks for me that the first and the last entry in your latlng array has the same values.

```
 AddPath(path) {
        // Flight path
        const len = path.length;
        let i = 0;
        for (let datas of path) {

            this.points.push({ lat: datas.lat, lng: datas.lng })
            console.log(this.points)
            if(i < len-1){
                  this.poly = new L.Polyline([this.points], { color: 'red', weight: 3 }).addTo(this.fg);
            }
            // zoom the map to the polyline
            this.map.fitBounds(this.fg.getBounds())
            i++;
        }
        new L.Marker(this.points[0], {
        icon: new L.DivIcon({
        html: ` <img src="assets/icon/B733.png" style="width:25px"/>`,
        iconSize: [20, 20],
        })

        }).addTo(this.map)
    }
```